# I am not able to see Create partition wizard in SQL Server Management Studio V18 for Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I want to do horizontal partitioning in my SQL Server. Some of the tutorials say I need to click the table -> Storage -> Click Partition. something like below.

[image]

Issue: though, for my case, I am only seeing "Manage compression". I am not seeing "Create partition", In addition, I am not able to see "FileGroups" at the database level.

I am using Azure SQL

No Partition option showing up:

[image]

No File group option visible:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS has that wizard blocked, as Azure SQL Database doesn't support using non-primary filegroups for partition schemes.  You can provide feedback for SSMS [here](https://aka.ms/sqlfeedback).

The DDL for partitioning in Azure SQL Database is the same as for regular SQL Server, so you can write it by hand, or use the SSMS wizard against a local SQL Server to generate the script.  Just remember to point all partitions to the primary filegroup.

Minimally on Azure SQL Database, this looks like:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pf(INT)  
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (1, 100, 1000);  

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ps  
AS PARTITION pf  
ALL TO ([Primary]);  

create table PartitionedTable(id int identity primary key, a int)
on ps(id);
```

Technically tables aren't partitioned.  Tables are comprised of one or more indexes, each of which may be stored on a filegroup or a partition scheme.  To see all your partitioned tables (here defined as a table whose main index is stored on a partition scheme), run a query like:

```
select schema_name(t.schema_id) schema_name, t.name table_name, ds.name partition_scheme
from sys.tables t
join sys.indexes i
  on t.object_id = i.object_id
join sys.data_spaces ds
  on i.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
where i.type in (0,1,5) --heap, CI, CCI
  and ds.type = 'PS' --partition scheme
```

Comment: Thanks @David. I don't need to create any filegroup. Right? Also, How can I see confirm whether the Table is partitioned? I don't see table partition as yes or no in Table properties for Azure SQL database in SSMS